# How do I restrict my search in dbpedia using SPARQL to "Persons" only

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am using a query to output the influences of all people listed in wikipedia (where possible). I am using http://dbpedia.org/snorql/. My code so far is:

```
SELECT *
WHERE {
?p a
<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person> .
?p <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/influenced> ?influenced.
}
```

The problem is that the influenced output includes things like genres and political ideologies. I want to restrict it to only output "people" and "**people** who were influenced by those people". Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT *
WHERE {
?p a
<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person> .
?p <dbpedia-owl:birthYear> ?birthYear.
?p <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/influenced> ?influenced.
?influenced a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person>.
}
```

**EDITED TO ADD BIRTH YEAR**

Comment: Thank-you but how do I pull out the Persons birthplace as well please?

Comment: It showing no result;  How can get details of a person say Deepika_Padukone

Comment: @WilliamGreenly Please help I need to get details of a person; Its showing no result in ; I tried the above query but its not working;